# Silva Polaris compass, use of the second dial numbered from 0 to 7

Tags: compasses

[image: compass Silva Polaris with two bezels]

I am looking for the use of the second (outer) dial numbered from 0 to 7 on the Silva Polaris compass.
This second dial rotates independently of the inner dial.

Comment: Please upload a better quality picture that is in focus. I can’t see any example of a Polaris compass with two dials on Google images.

Comment: BTW, the “dial” is called a “bezel”.

Comment: Thanks. I’m intrigued by this. Neither me or my friend (a very experienced mountaineer) have ever seen this or can think what it would be for. Maybe connected to days of the week, but we don’t know how.

Comment: Although he suggests emailing Silva as they’re quite responsive. If you get an answer, please post it here.

Comment: Thank you, I sent a message to Silva Canada.

Comment: I received a response from Silva : "The Silva Polaris was a Johnson Outdoors manufactured Silva compass that has been discontinued for some time now. Johnson Outdoors is no longer associated with Silva. I am sorry but I do not know the purpose of the second dial. As a long shot, Liberty Mountain in the US used to distribute Johnson Outdoors Silva compasses and now distributes the Swedeish designed ones now. If you reach out to them they may have carried this model at one point. Liberty Mountain" My Quest continue!

Comment: The outer dial looks original to me, it does not come off at all. I cross my fingers, and hope to get answers from Johnson Outdoors and/or Liberty Mountain

Comment: @TomasBy if you zoom in it has “Silva Polaris” stamped on the outer bezel.

Comment: @Darren it could still be some add-on, but if it is permanently attached then I guess it is original. Weird that there does not seem to be any other pictures of it.

Comment: Note that, for the full circle, it actually goes from 0 to 8. Each division is 1/8 of a circle. Each division is further divided into quarters, so the total number of subdivisions is 32, which is exactly how many *points* are in a compass. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is used to measure distance. You turn it on its side and roll it along a path on the map.  This means it has to correspond to a particular map scale (my first guess is 1:50,000, but that looks a bit off).  For a different scale you could do a simple conversion.

Can you tell me what the arc length of one major division is?  From the picture, it kinda looks like a little more than one inch (maybe 1.25" ?? ).  I can get the associated scale from that (i.e. what is the arc length between 6 and 7)

Comment: If you look at the smaller divisions, at the top in the image, they seems to be 1/4 inch, so major division one inch.

Comment: Well done. It is indeed 1 inch between two marks. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Dang! I was hoping for a slightly different number.  The best guess that i have (total WAG) is that the scale is 1:40000 and the major division is for a kilometer, which cant be right because the 1/4 increments don't make any sense for metric.  So I still say it is to measure distance, but I am stumped on the scale.

Comment: @Mike - if it is 1" scale will be 1:63,360 or inch per mile - used to be standard in the  Commonwealth (e.g. Canada, NZ, AU, UK) before metric conversion. Not sure if the UK still uses this scale as they still use mph on cars AFAIK. I thin US survey is still mile based too.

Comment: I did just find a reference that says "Most of Alaska has been mapped at 1:63,360."  which would fit spot on.  And I see that Bob beat me to it which makes way more sense.

Comment: @bob1 U.K. Ordnance Survey maps are metric these days. I’m sure you could still find imperial maps for those of my Dad’s generation.

Comment: @Mike - turns out the USA is now 1:24,000, or 1 inch/2000 feet, which just seems like a bizarre scale to me.

Comment: @Darren I've got some old inch to the mile OS maps. I planned to use them as wallpaper but they were too nice for that. I think the main UK maps were last produced in that scale in the 1960s

Comment: I have seen some modern 1:40000 maps in the UK. Harveys I think. A rather nice intermediate between 25000 and 50000. Perhaps this scale is used in other countries (but not France, I've got some maps for there)

Comment: Folks, it doesn't matter what the circumference or arc length is! If you know how many turns and fractions of a turn your measured map distance is, just reproduce the same distance down the side of the map's grid, or along its bar scale, and you have the scaled distance!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of additional items:

**Angular units** - Note that, for the full circle, it actually goes *from 0 to 8*. Each division is 1/8 of a circle. Each division is further divided into quarters, so the total number of subdivisions is 32, which is exactly how many points are in a compass. See 
[Points_of_the_compass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass)

**Distance measurement** - It doesn't really matter what the circumference or arc length is! If you know how many turns and fractions of a turn your measured map distance is, just reproduce the same distance down the side of the map's grid, or along its bar scale, and you have the scaled distance!
You can also measure a map distance using a piece of string. You don't need to know the length of the string other than to lay it down along the map grid.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the whole idea of this additional thingy is to measure inches. It would make more sense to claim it does not matter it is exactly eight in the full circle. I agree it does not really appear to be an optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: @TomasBy - if you look more closely at the image you will see that the 1/4 divisions go past 7, so as MartinF says - it goes from at least 0-7.75, or if you do a full circle 0-8 (actually back to 0 again).

Comment: I should have waited a bit before choosing Mike's answer. my excuses...
I believe that the fact that each division is one inch, divided into quarters, tilts scales on the side of a ruler-wheel. The division into eight is unusual, I agree. Perhaps this is a reason for its little distribution? But, then why is the system not found with other more practical divisions? Experienced mountaineers could perhaps judge the usefulness of the device.

Comment: @Laraison you can change the accepted answer if you wish.

Comment: @Laraison the size seems appropriate since it extends outside the square base of the compass on three sides. It could have been slightly smaller, but what for.

Comment: And in a MacGyver episode, he used it to make an odometer for his bicycle.  Nobody was asking how to do a simple linear conversion.  Your answer is like when a kid asks what an allen wrench is for, you say it makes a great hammer.  The question was "What was it designed for?" and the easy part is distance.   The interesting part is that it was designed for a specific scale (63,360), but its not an ordinary scale in the USA.  Johnson Outdoors is a US company, but most maps in the USA use different scales - a USGS topo map uses 1:24000 and BLM or forest service maps are typically 1:100,000.

Comment: @Mike - That's why i prefaced my answer with "A couple of additional items:" - i make some points additional to your answer.